# Nginx error : "Primary script unknown ", how can I resolve that ? Thank you

Tags: php, macos, nginx, virtualbox, debian-stretch

Config :

- > macOS Mojave
- > Debian 9.9.0 64bits on virtualbox 6.0.8, on port 192.168.56.50
- > php fpm 7.2 on debian
- > nginx/stable,now 1.16.0-1~stretch on debian

Nginx and php fpm have www-data as user.
Dirs :

- > lrwxrwxrwx  www-data www-data /var/www/all -> /media/sf_web
- > drwxrwx---  www-data www-data /var/www

Config nginx :
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name _;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
       root /var/www/all/;
       try_files $uri /index.html index.php;
       }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

When i do this command : sudo ls -l /var/www/all/ , i get :

> - drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf temp_converter
> - drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf myproject

I want to show projects folders under /media/sf_web using Firefox (or another web browser) but it doesn't work.
When i try to connect on this ip , nginx show "File not found" and in error log i see "Primary script unknow".

e.j :

- > http://192.168.56.50
- > http://192.168.56.50/myproject/index.php

Comment: what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Oh the command line, try `ls -l /var/www/all/`, what do you get? Is there any index files in there?

Comment: drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 704 Oct 30 2018 temp_converter
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 704 Oct 30  2018 myproject

Comment: Try adding an index file to the folder. It looks like there isn't one there. If your project is in `myproject/`, then add that to your root path.

Comment: Nginx doens't do Directory Index Listings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set a global `root` statement, so Nginx will look for PHP files in the default root. You need to move the `root` statement from inside the `location /` block into `server` block scope.

The `try_files` statement is completely wrong.

Try:

```
root /var/www/all/;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
...
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}
```

Comment: I have now a 403 forbidden : 
/var/www/all/index.html
 - Permission denied

Comment: I have solved , the problem was in /etc/group , there was multiple vboxsf
Thanks guys